# Error: [HPM] Invalid context. Expecting something like: "/api" or ["/api", "/ajax"]

Tags: angular

I am getting the following error from now while i haven't changed anything in my Angular 7 project. Till yesterday it wasn't giving this error.

```
Error: [HPM] Invalid context. Expecting something like: "/api" or ["/api", "/ajax"]
at Object.matchContext [as match] (E:\Java\GitWorkspace\FE-Router\node_modules\http-proxy-middleware\lib\context-matcher.js:40:9)
at shouldProxy (E:\Java\GitWorkspace\FE-Router\node_modules\http-proxy-middleware\lib\index.js:82:27)
at middleware (E:\Java\GitWorkspace\FE-Router\node_modules\http-proxy-middleware\lib\index.js:39:9)
at app.use (E:\Java\GitWorkspace\FE-Router\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:347:22)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Java\GitWorkspace\FE-Router\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (E:\Java\GitWorkspace\FE-Router\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at E:\Java\GitWorkspace\FE-Router\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (E:\Java\GitWorkspace\FE-Router\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (E:\Java\GitWorkspace\FE-Router\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at goNext (E:\Java\GitWorkspace\FE-Router\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\lib\middleware.js:16:16)
at processRequest (E:\Java\GitWorkspace\FE-Router\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\lib\middleware.js:64:26)
at ready (E:\Java\GitWorkspace\FE-Router\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\lib\util.js:52:12)
at handleRequest (E:\Java\GitWorkspace\FE-Router\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\lib\util.js:168:5)
at Promise (E:\Java\GitWorkspace\FE-Router\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\lib\middleware.js:39:7)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at middleware (E:\Java\GitWorkspace\FE-Router\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\webpack-dev-middleware\lib\middleware.js:38:12)
```

Here is my proxy.config.json

```
{
"/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8088",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
}
```

}

What's the reason behind this error message. How could I remove this error. Please help.

Comment: remove this "/*" and try

Comment: @HameedSyed still facing issue.

Comment: Just put this and try "/" i.e remove the * lexical character

Comment: No result buddy. same issue....

Comment: how did you try can you comment here?

Comment: 1. 
     {
    "/": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8088",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}

2.

     {
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8088",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}


3.
     {
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8088",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
        
    }
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/*` was not valid syntax. For proxying all requests we can use for example `/` or the wildcard `**` as stated in `http-proxy-middleware`

[View More Details Here](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#context-matching)

Answer (score 5):

in my case the error was caused by mixing "normal" paths and wildcard paths in the `context`

**invalid**

```js
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: ['/api', '/upload/**'],
    target: 'http://localhost:3000',
    secure: false,
    logLevel: 'debug'
  }
];
```

**valid**
note: `/**` removed after `/upload`

```js
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: ['/api', '/upload'],
    target: 'http://localhost:3000',
    secure: false,
    logLevel: 'debug'
  }
];
```